# How to count gaps in in monthly recurring events in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

Using postgresql 9.6

The problem is as follows, we have a database that tracks orders in a subscription business. Once a person subscribes an order is generated for them every month. Each person has the ability to skip a month (or skip a month for cycles, or 3 etc, effectively skipping x months). I'm trying to determine the number of people that have "skipped" in a given month.

We have an orders table that looks like this (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  person_id varchar,
  timestamp_ timestamp
);
```

I can use window functions to sequence the orders per person, like this:

```
    select timestamp_, person_id, row_number() 
           over (partition by person_id order by timestamp_)
    from orders
```

Output:

```
 timestamp_             person_id                      row_number
2017-03-14 12:38:38 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    1
2017-04-14 10:04:13 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    2
2017-07-14 10:05:17 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    3
2017-08-14 10:02:37 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    4
2017-09-14 10:04:37 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    5
2017-10-14 10:02:08 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    6
2017-11-14 10:05:35 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    7
2017-12-14 10:02:52 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    8
2018-01-14 10:05:38 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    9
2017-11-15 03:54:57 000b5c80-c9b8-11e7-a1c1-0242ac110003    1
2017-12-14 10:00:34 000b5c80-c9b8-11e7-a1c1-0242ac110003    2
2018-01-14 10:07:17 000b5c80-c9b8-11e7-a1c1-0242ac110003    3
2016-12-24 10:15:58 0017c8ad-b252-11e6-b4db-0100ab184d8f    1
2017-01-24 10:54:49 0017c8ad-b252-11e6-b4db-0100ab184d8f    2
```

I've also been playing with the lag function like this:

```
    select timestamp_, person_id,
      (date_trunc('month', timestamp_) - date_trunc('month',timestamp_)) 
      over (partition by person_id order by timestamp_))
    from orders;
```

Giving me a result like this:

```
timestamp_              person_id                           lag
2017-03-14 12:38:38 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    
2017-04-14 10:04:13 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    0 years 0 mons 31 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
2017-07-14 10:05:17 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    0 years 0 mons 91 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
2017-08-14 10:02:37 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    0 years 0 mons 31 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
2017-09-14 10:04:37 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    0 years 0 mons 31 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
2017-10-14 10:02:08 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    0 years 0 mons 30 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
2017-11-14 10:05:35 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    0 years 0 mons 31 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
2017-12-14 10:02:52 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    0 years 0 mons 30 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
2018-01-14 10:05:38 00050c43-08c5-11e7-b433-01007e15dd78    0 years 0 mons 31 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
2017-11-15 03:54:57 000b5c80-c9b8-11e7-a1c1-0242ac110003    
2017-12-14 10:00:34 000b5c80-c9b8-11e7-a1c1-0242ac110003    0 years 0 mons 30 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
2018-01-14 10:07:17 000b5c80-c9b8-11e7-a1c1-0242ac110003    0 years 0 mons 31 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
2016-12-24 10:15:58 0017c8ad-b252-11e6-b4db-0100ab184d8f    
2017-01-24 10:54:49 0017c8ad-b252-11e6-b4db-0100ab184d8f    0 years 0 mons 31 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
```

I need help combining the two queries and applying a `group by month` to count the number of people who skipped that month:

```
select month, count(person_id) as skips
from ( some inner query)
group by month
```

To get something like this:

```
Month       Number of people who skipped subscription 
2017-03-1    14
2017-04-1    8
2017-05-1    4
```

Comment: If a person has records from 01/2017 till 12/2017, i.e. lacking an entry for 01/2018, how do I know whether that person has ended subscription then or is merlely skipping months? Shall I count 01/2018 as skipped for this person or not? (If you answer: "skipped", then: if the last month was 12/1997 instead, has the person merely been skipping twenty years? ;-)

Comment: Good question, lets say we have an event of termination of subscription so we can demarcate those for skips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method that comes to mind is to generate a row for every person for each month between their first timestamp and their last one (you might want to use a fixed date for that).

Then, check to see which ones have an order:

```
select m.mon, count(*) as num_missing
from generate_series('2017-03-01'::timestamp, '2017-05-01'::timestamp, interval '1 month') m(mon) join
     (select person_id, min(timestamp_) as mints, max(timestamp_) as maxts
      from orders
      group by person_id
     ) p
     on m.mon between date_trunc('month', mints) and date_trunc('month', maxtx) left join
     orders o
     on p.person_id = o.personid and m.mon = date_trunc('month', o.timestamp_)
where o.person_id is null
group by m.mon
order by m.mon;
```

Comment: in the where clause you have `t.person_id`, looks like a typo as there is no t alias.

Comment: @maxTrialfire . . . Yes, that was a typo.